# Dependency inversion and eager loading

Tags: php, laravel

my question is how can someone use eagerloading when using the dependency inversion principle ?

in such case for exemple !

```
abstract class dbrepo
{
    public function findorfail($id)
    {
        return $this->model->findOrFail($id);
    } 
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You still use the `with()` method:

```
return $this->model->with('relation1', 'relation2')->findOrFail($id);
```

### Edit

Well, you could accept an array of relations to load as the second parameter.

```
public function findorfail($id, array $relations = [])
{
    $query = $this->model;
    if (!empty($relations)) {
        $query = $query->with($relations);
    }
    return $query->findOrFail($id);
}
```

However, at some point you will need to ask yourself how much of Eloquent are your going to try to re-implement in your repository pattern. On your `get()` method, are you going to add parameters for the where, order by, group by, limit, joins, eager loads, etc.? Are you going to re-implement the entire query builder inside your repository?

Comment: and what if i want to use the same method but with another model(that dosent have the same relations of course)? my question is how can i make it dynamic?

Comment: nice approche man but i dont know if it works,  but  i found that my code  already works find + eagerloading (the code  quoted with the question) ..anyway this is my first app ever , iv been learning php since 4 months now so i dont know alot about best practices etc... just testing stuff and asking question for the sake of  knowledge , Thank you man :)

Comment: @AchrafKhouadja Updated the code to fix one issue. Asking questions is a great way to learn. Keep it up! :)